# Multi Row Update Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_passenger_flight
ON Flight
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  IF @@ROWCOUNT= 0 RETURN
  SET NOCOUNT ON
 BEGIN TRY
 IF EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1
    FROM inserted I inner join PassengerForFlight PV ON I.flightnumber= PV.flightnumber)
    BEGIN
      ;THROW 50000, 'Cannot update, Passenger is linked to flight',1
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ;THROW
END CATCH   
END
```

It works perfectly for one row update. But when i updated multi rows it failed.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to change the join with **PassengerForFlight**? or must I also work with **Deleted** pseudo table because its a after update trigger?

Edit:
When i run this update-statement:

```
UPDATE Flight
SET gatecode = 'B'
WHERE flightcode = 'KL'
```

I've get the following message :
[image]

Thats correct, but this update statement touch two different flightnumbers. One thats not exist in PassengerForFlight and one that exists in PassengerForFlight.

What i want is:
1 row(s) affected and then the error message

Comment: How is it failing?

Comment: It catch only the latest update row

Comment: When handling a multi-row update, you have to code for multiple rows. Your code would only handle single rows at a time. Also, your trigger is not designed to roll back an error - it just notifies you of the error. I would look into an INSTEAD OF trigger, or code the data verification before submitting the data.

Comment: How about some details about the tables and some sample data? Are you saying that you want to allow some part of the update but throw an exception for others rows? That isn't how updates work. They are an atomic piece of work that either works or fails 100%.

Comment: @LaughingVergil That the trigger is not code for multiple rows is my whole point and question...

Comment: @SeanLange Why is it then possible to write multi row handle after update triggers?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your JOIN.  The problem is that you used IF EXISTS().  What you coded is:  "if there is ANY row in the `INSERTED` table that exists in the `PassengerForFlight` table, then throw an error.

Since you're throwing an error, the trigger will rollback any transaction that it is participating in.

One way to do what you want is change this to an INSTEAD OF trigger, and to PRINT a message instead of throwing an error.

Your current code's philosophy is "let the UPDATE happen, and if certain condition exists, throw an error and roll it back."   This can only happen in a way that affects the entire UPDATE (all rows).

I suggest a philosophy, of "Instead of the requested UPDATE, only UPDATE those rows that meet a certain condition.  If any rows in the requested UPDATE didn't meet that condition, then give the user a message."

Comment: Thanks for the information, so change the if exists() will not be enough to get the trigger multi row update ready?

Comment: If you keep it as an AFTER trigger, then the UPDATE will not be prevented by changing the IF EXISTS().   See the last two paragraphs I just added to my answer.